# Build-time errors when targeting device, fine in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, build-error, targeting

I have recently made two Frameworks (`Extensions` & `SpotifyAPI`), which are targeting iOS 10 just like my project. My phone is running iOS 12 beta `(16A5345f)`. Xcode is running `Version 10.0 beta 6 (10L232m)`.

Here is the project when I target the simulator or my device:

[image]

*Ignore the warnings, they are expected. The errors are not expected.*

For a reason I don't know, the Frameworks don't seem to be recognised when my iPhone is targeted. **ALL** these errors are functions, variables etc, which are apparently "unresolved identifiers" or "undeclared types" or "has no members" from my Frameworks.

Why does this **only** work for the simulator, and not my device? Is my Framework not supporting a certain type of architecture?

Here is my hiarachy:

[image]

I tried to run it in Xcode 9, but I got this:

[image]

So I deleted and reinstalled Xcode 10 but still with no luck.

How can I allow my project to run on my device?

---

**If you have any questions, please ask!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this was frustrating... but I know people will come across this problem in the future, so here the answer is. All you need to do is build the Frameworks **targeting your iOS device**, and then it will work completely fine. Apple, couldn't you make it any clearer?

However, this causes the opposite problem, that the device no longer works in the simulator.

**EDIT:**

I found this [Medium post about how to make a universal framework](https://medium.com/allatoneplace/writing-custom-universal-framework-in-xcode-9-and-ios-11-7a63a2ce024a), and got it to work